# Unable to find resources - Tomcat - Spring - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring, tomcat

I am trying to set up a small angularjs app. I am using SpringMVC to deliver the main template, on which I pretend start using Angular.

My problem is that when adding my modules, controllers, etc. to my html, the browser does not find them and the console reflects 404.
I have tried different variants (with/without slash and with ../ in the beginning of the src) but none will work. I have the feeling I am locating my resources wrongly.

This is how my project structure looks like

[image]

And here my home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/myController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span>Hiya!</span>
<div data-ng-app="myapp">
    <div data-ng-controller="myController"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am always getting this:

[image: console output]
[image: Network tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!
The js files apparently have to be under "static"

[image: This way it works]

Answer (score 0):

Your templates directory is at the same level of your javascript directory, and you need a file from the js directory from within the templates directory. You need to step down a level ("../") and then navigate to the folder with the desired javascript. So, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Would become this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you testing this project using a localhost server such as XAMPP?

Comment: I am locally deploying a war artifact through Intellij IDEA. On Tomcat

Comment: Makes sense they need to be under "static" :)

Answer (score 0):

With your project structure it will be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/controller/myController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already tried and just did again but it didn't work

Comment: what is the issue you are seeing in console?